# C# Implementing the CRUD operations in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, relational-database, crud

I'm trying to implement the create,delete and edit methods for my database but I don't know how. I thought Visual Studio generates it by itself but I'm getting a lot of errors.

I believe the main cause of errors is how I use id to find my products and categories. I've tried

- Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
- Category category = db.Categories.Find(new Category() { Id = id });

but they both don't work.

I've labelled the errors in Controllers/CategoryController.cs.

Error List (Right-Click -> Open image in a new tab)
[image]

Models/Product.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Inventory.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set;}
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Models/Category.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Inventory.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Controllers/CategoryController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Inventory.DAL;
using Inventory.Models;

namespace Inventory.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private InventoryContext db = new InventoryContext();

        // GET: Category
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Categories.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Category/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);  <--Line 31 Error 3 and 4
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Category/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Categories.Add(category);
                db.SaveChanges();      <-- Line 55 Error 5
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);<--Line 69 Error 6 and 7
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Category/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified; <--Line 86 Error 8
                db.SaveChanges(); <--Line 87 Error 9
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id); <--Line 100 Error 10 and 11
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Category/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id); <--Line 113 Error 12 and 13
            db.Categories.Remove(category);
            db.SaveChanges(); <--Line 115 Error 14 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose(); <--Line 123 Error 15
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

DAL/InventoryContext.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Inventory.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace Inventory.DAL
{
    public class InventoryContext
    {
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public InventoryContext()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>
            {
            new Product{Id=1,CategoryId=1,Brand="Coca Cola", Name="Coca Cola",Barcode="00001",Price=150},
            new Product{Id=2,CategoryId=1,Brand="Pepsi", Name="Pepsi",Barcode="00011",Price=150},
            new Product{Id=3,CategoryId=2,Brand="Homebrand", Name="Baked Beans",Barcode="0002",Price=250},
            new Product{Id=4,CategoryId=2,Brand="Homebrand", Name="Baked Patatos",Barcode="0022",Price=250}

            };
            Categories = new List<Category>
            {
            new Category{ID=1, Name="Drink", Products = Products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == 1).ToList() },
            new Category{ID=2,Name="Canned Food", Products = Products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == 2).ToList() }

            };
            foreach (var product in Products)
                product.Categories = Categories.Where(c => c.ID == product.CategoryId).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message says that an `int?` (nullable int) isn't the same thing as an `Inventory.Models.Category`.  Start there.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. If I can't use int to specify the ID then how am I suppose to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your InventoryContext. it needs to be inherited from DbCntext

Change your Inventorycontext as follow:

```
public class InventoryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public InventoryContext()
    {

        foreach (var product in Products)
            product.Categories = Categories.Where(c => c.ID == product.CategoryId).ToList();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(TeamMember member)
    {

        if (member.ImageFile != null)
        {
            if(member.ImageFile.ContentType!="image/png" && member.ImageFile.ContentType != "image/jpeg")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ImageFile", "Image file must be png or jpeg!");
                return View();
            }

            if (member.ImageFile.Length > 2097152)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ImageFile", "Image file must be less than 2MB!");
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ImageFile", "Image file is required!");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        _context.TeamMembers.Add(member);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }

    public IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var member = _context.TeamMembers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (member == null)
            return RedirectToAction("error", "dashboard");


        return View(member);

    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you posted two answers? Or did you just mean to edit the code from one into the other?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var member = _context.TeamMembers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

            if (member == null)
                return RedirectToAction("error", "dashboard");


            return View(member);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Delete(TeamMember member)
        {
            var existMember = _context.TeamMembers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == member.Id);

            if (existMember == null)
                RedirectToAction("error", "dashboard");

            FileManager.Delete(_env.WebRootPath, "uploads/teamMembers", existMember.Image);

            _context.TeamMembers.Remove(existMember);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).